# How to read docs as offline and write as (online & offline) in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Recently I have created a simple chat app using Cloud Firestore and React Native. Their offline and online synchronization is a pretty good feature.

But there is an expensive time consuming on loading(reading documents).
Although I paginated with 10 docs for every user (10 users), but still the loading messages is very slow, in a slow internet connection, it takes up to 10 seconds to load messages which is not a good experience.

Here when I enable offline mode it loads messages a bit faster (almost 3 seconds). But here is a problem:

**Now:**

Is possible to load messages as offline, and save messages in both(offline & online).

Or is there any other better way to load faster?

When I enable offline feature in firebase, it cant save messages in server, or I disable offline while saving messages, and when I load messages it load just offline messages.

Example:

```
async function getMessagesOfAllUser(userlist){
    let outstate = false, data = {};
    if (userlist !== null)
        for (let i = userlist.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            outstate = await this.getMessagesOfOneUsers(userlist[i].user);
            if (outstate !== false) data = { ...data, ...outstate };
            if (i === 0) {
                this.setState({ ...this.state, ...data });
            }
        }
}

function getMessagesOfOneUser(user) {
    return db.collection('users/'+user/+'/messages').orderBy("dt", "desc").limit(10).get().then(snap => {
        let l = snap.size;
        if (l > 0) {
            const ourMessage = this.state.me + user;
            this.lastVisible = { ...this.lastVisible, ...{ [user]: snap.docs[l - 1] } };
            for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                if (this.outState[ourMessage] !== undefined)
                    this.outState[ourMessage] = [...this.outState[ourMessage], snap.docs[i].data()];
                else this.outState[ourMessage] = [snap.docs[i].data()];
                if (i === l - 1) return this.outState;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: "But there is an expensive time consuming on loading(reading documents)." That depends on how you read it. A `get()` will always try to read from the server, but a `onSnapshot` will actually immediately fire with the local data, and only then check the server for fresh data. It'll be easier to help you if you show the [minimal code that reproduces what you current do](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can I use onSnapshot for reading multiple documents, specially for reading and listing messages?

Comment: didnt work onSnapshot

Comment: `onSnapshot ` can be called on a `DocumentReference` (in which case it'll give you a single `DocumentSnapshot`) and on a `Query` (in which case it'll give you a `QuerySnapshot`, which contains zero or more `DocumentSnapshot`s). If you're having trouble making that work, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that it'll be hard to help you further.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, thank you to reply,
Could you please see the xample in question, I have edited my question.
My code works very well, it gets 10 messages of 12 user.
But problem is it takes very time, even in good internet it takes about 7 seconds, in a bad internet it takes about 12 seconds.
when I call `disableNetwrok()` function using firebase it takes about 3 seconds which still is not good but, diffinitly is better than without `disableNetork()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `get()` (without arguments) to read a document, the Firestore client will always checks with the server to ensure you get the latest data.

You have two options to get the data from the local cache:

1. Use `get({ source: "cache" })` ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GetOptions.html)), which will return the document from the local cache. If the document doesn't exist in the local cache, it'll raise an error. In that case you'll still want to check against the server.
2. Use an `onSnapshot()` listener. When you attach this listener, it immediately calls back with the value from the local cache, as `get({ source: "cache" })` does. But it also checks with the server if there is any update to the data. If there is, it retrieves the updated document, updates the local cache, and calls your code again with the updated value.

Using `onSnapshot()` is usually recommended if you show the data in the user interface, as it means your UI reacts to changes in the data.

For more on this, see [How do I Enable Offline Support?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDvdAFP6OhQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=10&t=0s) in the [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) video series.

Comment: Hello @Frank thank you, as you can see my code, I have changed only `.get().then(snap=>{})` with `onSnapshot(snap => {})` but it doesnt work.
Could you please help me how change above code snipt from `get()` to `onSnapshot()` ?

Comment: Also I have changed, `.get()` with `.get("cache")` but it thros this error:
`Error: Query.get failed: First argument must be an object`

As I am using `react-native-firebase` it is enabled by default the offline support.

Comment: Here as I checked, it look which `onSnapshot()` function is not promise and does not return anything. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you very much, now { source: "cache" } is working fine,

Now the problem is:
When someone else send me message while I am offline. and when I gets online I cant access his message.
There maybe probem is I am getting messages only from **cache**, so is there any better way to solve this problem.

Comment: `onSnapshot` is the better way to listen for data that may or may not change.. `onSnapshot` indeed does not return a promise, since it may fire multiple times. You'll want to call `setState()` within the `onSnapshot` callback.

Comment: Thank you for your helping dear sir, now I will find a way for that.

Just I can not call setState within `onSnapshot` callback, because
calling setState within a `loop` make the app unresponsive for a while (untill loop gets finish).

because that I have called outside.

Comment: You could keep a count of all users, and then count for how many you got messages. Then once the counter is equal or greater to the number of users, call `setState(...)`. That way you will only call it once you've gotten messages for all users, but will call it for each update after that.